# Execute ajax request on form submit and don't wait for response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to make an AJAX request when the user attempts to submit a form. However, I don't want to wait for the response (I just want to trigger a script) and still submit the form immediately (or redirect the user).

I tried to to it this way (via jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form").submit(function(e)
    {
        // save object reference
        var form = this;

        // prevent form submit
        e.preventDefault();

        // trigger ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: { ... },
            cache: false
        });

        // submit form
        form.submit();

        // return false just in case
        return false; 
    });
});
```

But this won't work, because the AJAX request will in fact *not* be sent by the browser, if the form is submitted immediately afterwards (via `form.submit()` ).

I am a bit puzzled here... is there really no way to fire an AJAX request and redirect the browser immediately afterwards?

Comment: What makes you say the ajax call is not made?

Comment: What's your network tab say about the request?

Comment: @Archer (and tymeJV): the network tab of FireFox dev-tools do not report any request ever sent, nor does the server ever receive any such request.

Comment: What happens if you comment out `form.submit()` - does the ajax call work then?

Comment: @Archer yes, the ajax call will work then.

Comment: Move `form.submit();` into the ajax success callback.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: @Archer no, that won't work. The original question was "I want to make an AJAX request when the user attempts to submit a form. However, I don't want to wait for the response (I just want to trigger a script) and still submit the form immediately (or redirect the user).". If I move form.submit(); into the ajax success callback, the form won't be submitted immediately, the browser will wait until the ajax request is finished.

Comment: In that case just try putting the submit inside a `setTimeout` and delay it slightly.  Once the ajax call has actually been posted then submitting the form won't affect it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you create an infinite loop here. You are preventing the submit event and submitting it again at the end, but when you bind your function to the form's submission it will be called over and over. Instead, try to use Ajax states like success and complete; on success you submit data and on complete you redirect the page.

Comment: True, this does seem like an infinite loop, though there is never an infinite loop occurring. The form gets submitted by `form.submit()` within `.submit(function(e) {...});` and the browser opens the defined action by the form.

I didn't want to submit the form on success, because the success of the AJAX call is irrelevant to the form submission, but it could take a long time. I only wanted to trigger a script on the server via this AJAX call, immediately before the form is submitted. That's my goal ;).

In the end I created a different solution, independent of form submission.